# Switching between different jdk's running in same machine

Tags: java, java-8

I have two jdk running in my machine one is openjdk and one is Oracle jdk. I have two bash profiles and i switch between the profiles.

I have this in .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I have this in .bash_profile1

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and I do source .bash_profile1 to switch between profiles, So now when i do echo $JAVA_HOME. It should return path based on the bash profile which i have sourced.

It should return

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But it is returning JAVA_HOME which is there in other .bash_profile

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home.
```

What is the issue or Let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After chaging .bash_profile you should relaod it using this command `source ~/.bash_profile`.

but I advice you to use sdkman tool to switch between jdk versions easily https://sdkman.io/usage